# Finding a diagonal matrix with the form $P^{-1}AP$ and a basis order

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the matrix:

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}
      3 & 1 & 1           \\[0.3em]
      2 & 4 & 2 \\[0.3em]
      1           & 1 & 3
    \end{bmatrix}$$

It has the eigen-values: $\lambda = 2,6$.

Now, $V_{\lambda=2}$ is spanned by $\{ (1,-1,0), (1,-2,1) \}$ and $V_{\lambda=6}$ is spanned by $\{ (3,2,1) \}$

We have those vectors as a basis of $\mathbb{Q}^3$ and therefore; if we denote $P=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ then:

$$ P^{-1}AP =  \begin{bmatrix}
      2 & 0 & 0           \\[0.3em]
      0 & 2 & 0 \\[0.3em]
      0           & 0 & 6
    \end{bmatrix}$$

It happened to be that $v_1 = (1,-1,0), v_2 = (1,-2,1), v_3 = (3,2,1)$ - But how can one tell this (the order of the basis) without any trial and error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little bit of leeway when it comes to diagonalization.

There are multiple ways to diagonalize a matrix (depending on how you arrange your eigenvalues), but a simple rule to check whether one will work. Let me explain.

In the example you have given, you set up your diagonal matrix of eigenvalues as:

$$D = P^{-1}AP = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 6  \end{bmatrix}$$

But, really there is no reason why you couldn't write:

$$D' = P'^{-1}AP'= \begin{bmatrix}6 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 2  \end{bmatrix}$$

However, once your diagonal matrix of eigenvalues $D$ is set, we need to choose our matrix of eigenvectors $P$ in a special way. The condition (or rule) that we need to satisfy is to arrange the columns of the matrix $P$ so that the first column is an eigenvector of the first eigenvalue in the diagonal matrix $D$, the second column is a (different) eigenvector corresponding to the second eigenvalue in $D$, and so on.

So, for instance, the matrix $D$ above could have the following matrix $P$ (where we have used the eigenvectors as given in the statement of the question):

$$P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 3 \\ -1 & - 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Each column of $P$ is an eigenvector of the corresponding entry in the matrix $D$.

For the matrix $D'$, where the first eigenvalue is 6, our matrix $P'$ would have to have the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue 6 in its first column:

$$P = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & - 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

The bottom line: there is no fixed, unique way to diagonalize a matrix, since we can rearrange the eigenvalues in the diagonal matrix. However, once we set our matrix $D$, the matrix $P$ must correspond to that $D$ by having the corresponding eigenvectors arranged in the same order as their eigenvalues appear in the diagonal matrix.

Comment: Let me get it straight (just to make sure I got it): I can choose any eigen-vector corresponding to it's eigen-value?

Comment: Pretty much. You can make your diagonal eigenvalue matrix however you want, then just line up the eigenvectors according to those eigenvalues

Comment: But if some $\lambda$ appears more than once then we must pick linearly independent vectors, aren't we?

Comment: Exactly. In the example you gave, $\lambda = 2$ had multiplicity 2, and we need to make sure that we use both linearly independent eigenvectors in constructing $P$

Comment: For the matrix $D'$ you mentioned: Can I switch $v_2,v_3$? (The two eigen-vectors of $\lambda = 2$)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you got the third eigenvector wrong. $v_3 = (1,2,1)$

And secondly, I assume you mean the order of writing the basis, i.e., why is $v_1$ first. 
Actually, that doesn't matter. You have:
$$P^{-1}AP=D$$
Where $D$ is the diagonalized matrix.
Suppose, just for example, you want to see what happens if you write $P$ with its first two columns swapped. Then instead of taking conjugating by $P$, you conjugate by $PB$, where:
$$B =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) $$
Now we have:
$$(PB)^{-1}A(PB)=B^{-1}P^{-1}APB=B^{-1}DB=\tilde{D}$$
Where $\tilde{D}$ is also a diagonalized matrix, but with its first two eigenvalues swapped.

To summarize: It doesn't matter, it'll just determine the form of the diagonalized matrix. (The order of appearance of the eigenvalues in it)

Comment: Thank you but hmm.. what you did here is sort of a fixation whereas I wish to identify the "right" order (to get a diagonal matrix) a-priori.

Comment: No, what I did here is to prove that you get a diagonal matrix no matter how you organize the vectors. (And you get the eigenvalues in order of the eigenvectors)

Comment: Can you explain how did you pick matrix $B$?

Comment: Standard matrix to substitute the 1st and 2nd row.
You learn about these when learning about row operations, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Operations